# Theoretical justification for the range of validity of the approximation $R(T)\approx R(T_0)[1+\alpha (T-T_0)]$

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, material-science, error-analysis, approximations

In the experiment for calibrating a platinum resistance thermometer, we are always approximating the resistance of the platinum thermometer by $$R(T) \approx R_0 (1+\alpha T),$$ taking the reference at $0^o C$ and using Celsius scale.

We measure temperature by a thermometer of least count $0.5^o C$, and resistance of the platinum thermometer by a Carey Foster bridge which is sensitive up to $0.005\Omega$.

We work in the range of $0^o C-100^o C$.

**Qusetion:** How can we justify (without saying that, experimentally it is observed...) the usage of the approximation for $R(T)$ for this temperature range given the precision of our apparatus?

---

What I’m basically asking is the justification for ignoring the higher order terms in the Taylor expansion of $R(T)$ at $T_0$ *for ranges as large as* $100^o C$?

Comment: Well, you could look at the tables of resistance vs temperature for your particular resistor and see how linear it is.

Comment: I asked on theoretical grounds...

Comment: Well, the theory is in the Taylor expansion. The check if it is reasonable is the actual data for you particular material. Deriving resistivity vs temperature for an arbitrary material across a large temperature range is, well, quite difficult.

Comment: @JonCuster So the range of validity comes *purely* from experiment?

Comment: Indeed. You might be interested in https://tsapps.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=904572 - it would suggest that the range should be based on the particular calibration requested.

Comment: As written the question makes no sense since T has a dimension, so 1 + T is non-sensical. You need a prefactor (in 1/degree).

Comment: For the range [0, 100], you are better off using R(50) as your constant rather than R(0).

Answer (score 2):

The response of a platinum resistance thermometer (PRT) is better approximated with the so-called *Callendar-Van Dusen* equation (this is defined in the standard IEC EN 60751):

$R(t) = \begin{cases}
    R_0\left[1+At+Bt^2+C(t-100\,{}^\circ\mathrm{C})t^3\right]& t<0 \\[5mm]
    R_0(1+At+Bt^2)& t\geqslant 0
    \end{cases}$

where $t$ is the Celsius temperature and the nominal values of the coefficients are (a calibration can give more accurate values)

$\begin{aligned}
    &R_0 = 100\,\Omega \\
    &A = 3.9083\times 10^{-3}/{}^\circ\mathrm{C}, \\
    &B = -5.775\times 10^{-7}/{}^\circ\mathrm{C}^2, \\
    &C = -4.183\times 10^{-12}/{}^\circ\mathrm{C}^4,
    \end{aligned}$

For $t$ from $0\,{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$ to $100\,{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$, the response is

$R(t) = R_0(1+At+Bt^2)$

If you use instead the linear approximation $ R(t) = R_0(1+\alpha t)$, you will measure the temperature $t'$ such that (assuming that $R_0$ is the same for the two equations; otherwise, modify accordingly)

$R_0(1+At+Bt^2) = R_0(1+\alpha t')$

The difference $\Delta t = t'-t$ is the measurement error that you get from using the linear approximation. Substituting $t' = t+\Delta t$ in the above equation and simplifying, you get

$At+Bt^2 = \alpha(t+\Delta t)$

from which

$\Delta t = \dfrac{1}{\alpha}\left[(A-\alpha)t+B t^2\right].$

The above equation represents a parabola, and substituting the value of $\alpha$ that you use you can find the maximum error along the whole measurement range. For instance, if you use $\alpha = 3.85\times 10^{-3}/{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$, the *nominal* average temperature coefficient from $0\,{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$ to $100\,{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$ (according to the EU standards, for a US PRT you may get $\alpha = 3.92\times 10^{-3}/{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$), the error $\Delta t$ is maximum at $t = 50{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$ and $(\Delta t)_\mathrm{max}\approx 0.38{}^\circ \mathrm{C}$. This specific case is represented in the figure below (own picture):

[image: Pt100 transfer characteristic]

Depending on your application and the accuracy class of the PRT, you can then evaluate whether you can consider the above error negligible or not.